# Access a file from a JAR in the same folder

Tags: java, file, jar, directory, executable-jar

I need to acces (create and read) a file from a JAR file (executable jar),
and that file should be created in the same directory as the JAR

I tried 
    `this.getClass().getResource("myFile")`
 but since the jar has packages in it, it won't work..

I also tried write just
`File f = new File("myFile");
f.createNewFile();`

and that works if i execute the JAR from the terminal, but if i execute the JAR by double-clicking it, the file is created in my home directory -.-''

how do i access a file being SURE that that file is in the SAME directory as the JAR file?

(of course also getting the jar absolute path would do the trick since i can get the parent folder from it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you the full path to the Jar:

```
String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

EDIT: sorry, was in javascript mode when I wrote that :). As was so politely requested, in a static method you should be able to do this:

```
String path = Me.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

(where the class name is `Me`).

Comment: thanks a lot! so that line returns the same value even if i run it from different classes in the jar right?

Comment: As long as they are all in the exact same jar, yes they should.

Comment: `var path`? Mixed metahaphors :) Also explain how to to this in a static method.

Comment: yep i figured it out, now that i've been able to testing i'm highlighting the green tick!

Comment: What if I want to get the path of the DIRECTORY in which the jar file is located, rather than the exact .jar path. How can I do this ? Actually I want to write a new file in the same directory as the directory in which jar is present.

Comment: `new File(path).getParentFile()` will give you the directory.